# Spliting a list of lists into sublists

Tags: r, list, split

Consider the following (simple) list of lists:

```
big_lst = list(list(rnorm(3), rnorm(4)), list(rnorm(3), rnorm(4)))

#> big_lst
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1]  0.63620243 -0.01875264 -2.77235708

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1]  1.0527421 -0.3302443  1.2028328 -0.4019282


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] -1.6071500 -0.2870488 -0.1432817

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1]  0.7149935 -0.3090975  1.0108511  1.0419313
```

From this list, I would like to create two sublists as follows:

- The first list would be a list of all first elements of each sublist of `big_lst`: in other words, the first list should contain **[1][[1]]** and **[2][[1]]**.
- The second list would be a list of all second elements of each sublist of `big_lst`: in other words, the second list should contain **[1][[2]]** and **[2][[2]]**.

Is there an easy way of doing that? I have the feeling this has to do with the method `split` but I wasn't able to make it work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## Better example data
big_lst <- list(list(1:2, LETTERS[1:2]), list(3:4, LETTERS[3:4]))

## Use do.call to construct and evaluate a call that will look like:
##     mapply(list, big_lst[[1]], ..., big_lst[[n]], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
do.call(mapply, c(list, big_lst, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "A" "B"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
split(do.call(c, big_lst), 1:2)
```

Benchmarks:

```
big_lst <- rep(big_lst, 100)
josh <- function() do.call(mapply, c(list, big_lst, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
matthew <- function() split(do.call(c, big_lst), 1:2)
microbenchmark(josh(), matthew())
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
#     josh() 351.5 362.4  375.5 397.0 3191.9   100
#  matthew() 142.6 147.6  151.8 159.1  239.3   100
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However I get the following error: `> test = split(do.call(c, big_lst), 1:2)
Error in do.call(c, big_lst) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function`

Comment: You probably have a variable named `c` in your workspace, replace `c` with `base::c` or `'c'`.

Comment: Great thanks. It works. But how can I access the subslits then?

Comment: @Mariam ... ? with brackets?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant, but I figured it out. Thanks!